# jQuery Easy Accordion plugin not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, plugins, cross-browser

I'm using the Easy Accordion plugin (source = http://www.madeincima.it/en/articles/resources-and-tools/easy-accordion-plugin/) on my site and it's not functioning properly in IE (any version).

The issue is with the rotation of the dt element, I'm using 
`filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)` in CSS for the rotation and according to web developer tools in IE it's rotating the dt container but not the contents.

No idea how to fix, tried stripping the plugin down and using the demo provided on the source page, same result. You can see the result here - www.glosnut.co.uk

Plugin is supposed to function fine in IE, it's also working fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You only use the vendor prefixes for Firefox and WebKit for the `transform` and `transform-origin` properties (and perhaps more). This stops it from working in IE9+ and Opera.

You should add the -o- (older opera), -ms- (IE9) and prefixless versions (modern IE, Opera, and Firefox).

```
.easy-accordion dt {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

There are possibly other prefixes you need to add too. I've not looked into IE8 and below. How far back do you need to support?

If these rules come from the plug-in itself, it is not very future friendly or well coded, so I’d recommend to look for a more up to date plugin.